# SVN and RTC Integration

Tags: svn, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I have a requirement integrate RTC(Jazz) and SVN(Subversion) inorder to link the svn commits to RTC workitems.

Please share the process to be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the work items to the Subversion commit by following the procedure mentioned in the official documentation here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_7.0.1/com.ibm.team.scm.svn.doc/topics/t_link_workitems.html

This works and currently using the same.